# Cannot connect to database with MySQLi but can with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I recently discovered that the MySQL extension has been deprecated in PHP and will soon be removed. I decided to start using MySQLi however when attempting to convert my old code to the new extension, I receive an access denied error:

```
Connect Error (1045) Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I receive the error when using this code:

```
$connect = new mysqli("localhost","root","password1");
$connect->connect();
```

But it works fine when I use this code:

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password1");
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need that: `$connect->connect()`

Comment: The parameter is a comma delimited string of the server details.

Comment: Thank you, jreuab. I no longer received the error after removing `$connect->connect()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mysqli` version of `mysql_connect()` is `mysqli_connect()`. If you look [over here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) you can see that `mysqli_connect()` is an alias of the constructor of an `mysqli` object instead of one of it's methods. I hope this clears things up for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your systex is wrong. `$connect = new mysqli("localhost","root","password1");`

You forgot database name

`$connect->connect()` is not needed

Answer is :

`$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","mypassw","mybatadase");`

`$query = "SELECT name FROM mytable";`

`$result = $connect->query($query);`

//display information:

`while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row["name"] . "<br>";
}`

Comment: That's actually not true, please have a look [over here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php). `dbname` is optional, since it can also provided within a SQL query like this: `SELECT * FROM dbname.table`.